# A tela do MacBook Pro Retina está quebrando o layout no CSS do bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, osx, mac

Como eu poderia resolver isso, já tentei isso mais não funcionou:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-6.widescreen {
        width: calc(100%/2.05);
    }
}
```

Como está aparecendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como deveria aparecer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não sei se vai resolver, mas vou te dar uma dica sobre @media e vendo prefix. Não escreve o CSS da forma que está, mesmo parecendo correto. Separe cada Vendor prefix em uma regra. tipo `@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) { }` e depois outro sem o vendo prefix `@media only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) { }`

Comment: Os dois exemplos possuem a mesma resolução de tela?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema, era uma coisa simples, a div da coluna de cima, que englobava o botão sair do jogo e as vidas estava fechando no lugar errado, justamente no final de tudo.